# My for loop and conditional return confusion

Tags: loops, iterator

I wrote some code to return True for all the even numbers in a given list. It only returns the first number.

When I write the function `iseven(L)`, and I define it as:

```
for i in L: print i;
```

I print the function and get all the numbers in my list. But when I do:

```
for i in L, if i%2==0, return True
```

suddenly it only returns the first number in the list.

```
def iseven(L):
    for i in L:
        print (i)
        #if i%2==0:
        #return True
        #else:
        #return ''
```

The commented out lines are what I want my code to be, but since it's only spitting out the first number in the list, I checked the code with `print (i)` and it shows every number.

Comment: Please specify the programming language of the code in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Def number(list):

  for num in list: 
    # checking condition 

    if num % 2 == 0: 

      print(num, end = " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

If-statements are a once-and-done deal. What you're looking for is a for-loop that goes through each number or object you have and can run code for each - in this case, your if and print statements. After the for-loop is done then you can exit.

In Python:

```
def iseven:
   found = False
   for i in list:
      if i % 2:
         print(i)
         found = True
    return found
```

Note: The value of found is only returned once. If you want to return multiple values, not just print them like with i, then you need a data structure like an array.